# Change row name returns "duplicate 'row.names' are not allowed" in R

Tags: r, row

I've tried change row names from formate from "data07_2470178_2" to "2470178" by following code:

```
rownames(df) <-regmatches(rownames(df), gregexpr("(?<=_)[[:alnum:]]{7}", rownames(df), perl = TRUE))
```

But it returns following error:

```
Error in `.rowNamesDF<-`(x, value = value) : duplicate 'row.names' are not allowed
```

The dataset briefly looks like this:

```
                    1  2   3  4
data143_2220020_1  24  87  3  32
data143_2220020_2  24  87  3  32
data105_2220058_1  26  91  3  36
data105_2220058_2  26  91  3  36
data134_2221056_2  13  40  3  17
data134_2221056_1  13  40  3  17
```

And I'd like my dataset looks like this. For every original row only remain the one ended with "_2":

```
          1  2   3  4
2220020  24  87  3  32
2220058  26  91  3  36
2221056  13  40  3  17
```

I really don't understand why is this case? Also, how can I change row name correctly? Could anyone help? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you provide the contents of `rownames(df)`? Also is it your intent to replace the entire `df` data.frame? Or did you mean `rownames(df)<-...` rather than `df<-...`?

Comment: How does "data07_2470178_2" turn to "2370178" ? Do you mean "2470178" instead? You cannot have duplicate rownames in your data meaning it would give the same row name if you have one entry as "data07_2470178_2" and other as "data07_2470178_3". Can you show the expected output for your example?

Comment: Sorry it should be rownames(df) and I has re-edited the questions. I just want rename the rownames of df

Answer (score 0):

If you want to remove rows based on rownames, you can use :

```
rn <- sub('.*_(\\d+)_.*', '\\1', rownames(df))
df1 <- df[!duplicated(rn), ]
rownames(df1) <- unique(rn)
df1
#         1  2 3  4
#2220020 24 87 3 32
#2220058 26 91 3 36
#2221056 13 40 3 17
```

However, `unique(df)` would automatically give you only unique rows and you can change the rownames based on above method.

**data**

```
df <- structure(list(`1` = c(24L, 24L, 26L, 26L, 13L, 13L), `2` = c(87L, 
87L, 91L, 91L, 40L, 40L), `3` = c(3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L), `4` = c(32L, 
32L, 36L, 36L, 17L, 17L)), class = "data.frame", 
row.names = c("data143_2220020_1", 
"data143_2220020_2", "data105_2220058_1", "data105_2220058_2", 
"data134_2221056_2", "data134_2221056_1"))
```

Comment: Well it returns error with: Error in `.rowNamesDF<-`(x, value = value) : invalid 'row.names' length. I guess it's caused by different length between df1 and unique(rn) since rn are all 1 to n with no duplicate value but df1 is shorter as df do have duplicate value.

Comment: I am unsure about the error. This seems to work for the example shared. Can you check with the data I have added in my post? If it still doesn't work can you add your data using `dput`?